# How to know which user entered certain data access?

Tags: ms-access, enter

I am currently working on a project for myself and I'm creating a database for an Institute that helps students prepare for grade 12. I have thought about this topic for quite a while and did not have any efficient solution. However, I think if I added a field like "Entered by" in each table, it's datatype will be Lookup wizard. I will take the list from an admin table. 
[Look here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfi2w.png)

However this does not seem to be efficient since other users might be able to infiltrate the tables and change data. My apologies for my English and any lack of  basic knowledge in access. I'm still a student.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found an answer, you just need to do it in a form. Have the login form opened and connect its value to where you need. For example, if you need the name of the user in the open login from, you just create an "Entered by" field and make its default value equal to forms!login!username.